# How to fix beforeEachProviders (deprecated on RC4)

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, angular2-testing

Ive just upgraded Angular2 from RC3 to RC4 ...

```
import {
  expect, it, iit, xit,
  describe, ddescribe, xdescribe,
  beforeEach, beforeEachProviders, withProviders,
  async, inject
} from '@angular/core/testing';
```

In my unit test I have the following code ...

```
beforeEachProviders(() => [
    {provide: Router, useClass: MockRouter}
]);
```

This works fine but since moving to RC4 I have a deprecation warning on `beforeEachProviders`.

Anyone know what the new way of doing things is? Or should I import `beforeEachProviders` from somewhere else instead of '@angular/core/testing'?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You will need to import addProviders from @angular/core/testing.

Instead of:

```
beforeEachProviders(() => [
    {provide: Router, useClass: MockRouter}
]);
```

You'll want to do this:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    addProviders([
        {provide: Router, useClass: MockRouter}
    ])
});
```

Source: [RC4 Changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)

Comment: Thank you ever so much - you use of addProviders is correct - your use of provide is not necessary (and probably deprecated). Your reference to the change log is essential - many many thanks. So helpful I am extremely thankful. Saved me so much time!

Comment: provide() has been deprecated, but do you use instead?

Comment: @wholladay A plain object, see the difference http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12924184

Comment: It appears that addProviders is gone at rc.6.  Not sure what to use instead yet.

Comment: How to fix it in rc.6? beacause addProvider was removed from @angular/core/testing.

Comment: You need to use TestBed.configureTestingModule instead. Here's an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38914457/angular-2-testbed-with-mocks)

Answer (score 14):

After reviewing a few other documents, it appears you want:

```
beforeEach(() => TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        providers: [
            { provide: Service, useClass: MockService }
        ]})
    );
```

Source: https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection

Answer (score 1):

Here's a complete example, for a Window reference service:

```
import { TestBed, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { WindowRef } from './window-ref';

describe('WindowRef', () => {
  let subject: WindowRef;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        WindowRef
      ]});
  });

  beforeEach(inject([WindowRef], (windowRef: WindowRef) => {
    subject = windowRef;
  }));

  it('should provide a way to access the native window object', () => {
    expect(subject.nativeWindow).toBe(window);
  });
});
```