# Angular 2 TestBed with mocks

Tags: unit-testing, angular, mocking, testbed, angular2-providers

I am trying to test a component which uses another service. And I want to isolate the component by providing a mock for the service. Before RC5 I can simply use `addproviders` which is now deprecated and will be removed by the next RC. Instead I have to use the `TestBed`. When I provide the mock angular for some reason keep looking for the services that the mock depends on. And throws a `DI exception`. When I provide all the dependencies the test works but I don't want to repeat myself for each test suite. And this breaks basic OO principles.
My test suite:

```
describe('Component: DummyRestApi', () => {

  class DummyRestApiTestService {

    GetAll() {

      return Rx.Observable.create(observer => {

        let data:Data[] = [];

        data.push({
          id: 0,
          data: 'data'
        });

        observer.next(data);
        observer.complete();

      });
    }

    Add(data) {
    }
  }
  let fixture;
  let myMockWindow:Window;
  // ToDo use the mocks
  beforeEach(() => {
    myMockWindow = <any> {location: <any> {hostname: '127.0.0.1'}};
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [DummyRestApiComponent],
      providers: [
        // ServerAddressResolverService,
        DummyRestApiComponent,
        // ConfigurationService,
        {provide: DummyRestApiService, useClass: DummyRestApiTestService},
        // {provide: Window, useValue: myMockWindow}
      ],
      imports: [FormsModule, HttpModule]
    });
    TestBed.compileComponents().catch(error => console.error(error));


    // addProviders([
    //   DummyRestApiComponent,
    //   {provide: DummyRestApiService, useClass: DummyRestApiTestService},
    // ]);
  });


  describe('Initializing', () => {

    beforeEach(async(() => {
      console.log('Compiling');
      TestBed.compileComponents().catch(error => console.error(error));
      console.log('Compiling again');
    }));

    it('should create an instance', async(() => {
        var fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DummyRestApiComponent);
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(fixture.debugElement.componentInstance).toBeTruthy();
      }
    ));

});
```

Angular 2.0.0-RC5

Comment: I confirmed this. You have to specify the imports for the service as if it wasn't mocked. At least in RC5. The test will use the mock service, though.

Answer (score 6):

Note that Patrick Ineichens answer uses provide, which is deprecated.

```
 providers: [provide(TodoService, { useValue: this.service })]
```

should instead read:

```
 providers: [{provide:TodoService, useValue: this.service }]
```

Answer (score 2):

I've just updated my seed project to RC5 and my test suite for a simple todo component looks like this:

```
import { provide } from '@angular/core';
import { TestBed, ComponentFixture, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';

import { TodoModule } from './todo.module';
import { TodoComponent } from './todo.component';
import { Todo, TodoService } from './todo.service';

class MockTodoService {
    get todos$(): Observable<Todo[]> {
        return Observable.of<Todo[]>([
            { task: 'Task 1', description: 'Description 1', completed: false },
            { task: 'Task 2', description: 'Description 2', completed: false }
        ]);
    }

    loadAll() { }

    add(newTodo: Todo) { }
}

describe('TodoComponent', () => {

    beforeEach(() => {
        this.service = new MockTodoService();

        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [TodoModule],
            providers: [provide(TodoService, { useValue: this.service })]
        });

        this.fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TodoComponent);
    });

    it('should print out todo tasks', async(() => {
        this.fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
            let element = this.fixture.nativeElement;
            this.fixture.detectChanges();

            expect(element.querySelectorAll('li').length).toBe(2);
        });
    }));

    it('should call the service on init', async(() => {
        this.fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
            spyOn(this.service, 'loadAll');
            this.fixture.detectChanges();

            expect(this.service.loadAll).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
    }));
});
```

The seed project itself can be found at https://github.com/froko/ng2-seed-webpack

Hope this helps.

Comment: But the [RC5 change log](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes-1) also states "`ngModel` is now always asynchronous when updating. This means that in tests, instead of calling `ComponentFixture.detectChanges`, you'll need to use `ComponentFixture.whenStable`, which is asynchronous." You are already using `whenStable` but you're also still using `detectChanges`. Is it possible that your test will still work if you now just remove `this.fixture.detectChanges()`?