# How to fix "Cannot read injector property of null" bug in Angular 2?

Tags: unit-testing, angular

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38136059/how-to-fix-beforeeachproviders-deprecated-on-rc4) describes how to update Angular 2 after the `beforeEachProviders` function was deprecated.

But having done that, I get the error `Cannot read property 'injector' of null`

My test is relatively basic:

```
import { inject, addProviders } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { MyComponent } from './my.component';

describe('Foo', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        addProviders([{
            provide: MyComponent,
            useClass: MyComponent
        }]);
    });

    it('foo', inject([MyComponent], (e: MyComponent) => {
        expect(true).toEqual(true);
    }));
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

addProviders is also deprecated is favor of TestBed.

```
import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';
import { MyComponent } from './my.component';

// This should only be called once.
TestBed.initTestEnvironment(
    BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting());

describe('Foo', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [MyComponent],
      });
      TestBed.compileComponents();
    });

    it('foo', async(() => {
        let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(true).toEqual(true);
    }));
});
```

Angular2 RC5

Comment: I get an error ` Cannot set base providers because it has already been called` when I do it this way, but the tests work when I move the `initTestEnvironment` call to the `beforeEach` (having to do `TestBed.resetTestEnvironment` in an `afterEach` if you want to run more than one test as a result). The tests work, although strange that this is the case. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Calling initTestEnvironment before and resetTestEnvironment after each test is fine, but ideally you'd just call init once across all your tests. The Webpack example shows putting it in the karma shim file. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html